# Ruby Array#to_yaml doesn't call to_yaml recursively

Tags: ruby, yaml

The following code

```
require 'yaml'

class MyObject
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def to_yaml()
    @value + @value
  end
end

puts [MyObject.new("a"), MyObject.new("b")]
```

Generated the following output on Ruby 2.1.3p242:

```
---
- !ruby/object:MyObject
  value: a
- !ruby/object:MyObject
  value: b
```

Where I expected it to be

```
---
- aa
- bb
```

As if I called `to_yaml` on every object inside the Array:

```
puts [MyObject.new("a").to_yaml, MyObject.new("b").to_yaml]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm leaving the previous answer as well, since it might come in handy for someone, but here's the better solution.

I've actually over-simplified the original problem. I'm trying to get my custom object to be rendered as a YAML sequence `[1, 2, 3, ...]`.
The previous answer could work for objects that are being rendered as Strings.

Here's the working version:

```
require 'yaml'

class MyObject
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def encode_with coder
    coder.tag = nil
    coder.seq = [@value, @value]
  end
end

puts [MyObject.new("a"), MyObject.new("b")].to_yaml
```

Some references:

http://blog.mustmodify.com/pages/psych-ruby-1-9-yaml

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych/Coder.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm replacing the `visit_Array` method of the `Psych::Visitors::YAMLTree`

```
class MyVisitor < Psych::Visitors::YAMLTree
  def visit_Array o
    super o.map { |i| i.respond_to?(:to_yaml) ? i.to_yaml : i }
  end
end
```

Then, I'm dumping the YAML this way:

```
a = [MyObject.new("a"), MyObject.new("b")]
visitor = MyVisitor.create
visitor << a
puts visitor.tree.yaml
```